# Is it possible to use constructor like a callable object?

Tags: php

I have a class "Human"

```
class Human
{
    private $name, $age;
    public function __construct($name, $age)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->age = $age;
    }
}
```

And data to construct objects of this class

```
$data = [["John", 23], ["Nick", 32], ["Ann", 17]];
```

I need to construct array of objects of my class. That's the way i wrote earlier:

```
foreach($data as $item)
{
    //My real class containts much more fields.
    $humans[] = new Human($item[0], $item[1]); 
}
```

Can i use `call_user_func_array` or something like this to create instances much easier?

```
foreach($data as $item)
{
    $humans[] = call_user_func_array('Human::__construct', $item);
}
```

Comment: look at reflection https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php